# Does Facebook Messenger Bot provide information about the channel where the message was originated?

Tags: android, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm having a problem with the `lite` version of `messenger` (android only)

This version of the application does not support `bot` messages with `templates` or `buttons` (including the get_started button)

In my case this is an example:

[image]

I could not find a parameter in the `webhooks` to provide the user's platform. 
So I have to `ask the user`: do you use the lite version? 
And then set a different flow.

But this means that I must also give the possibility to disable the lite mode when browsing from the web or from the non-lite application (to guarantee a better `user experience`)

Does Facebook Messenger Bot provide information about the channel where the message was originated ?

Answer (score 2):

This information is not provided via webhook, currently. The closest you can get is detecting user agent in the webview.

A not ideal but doable option would be to have something like a 'Switch to Lite' button in the persistent menu

Comment: that's what I feared: /

Answer (score -1):

One way to identify where message event originates from is to use the `payload`s. You can specify a unique payload when setting up your bot and check what you receive to react on. `get_started`, `persistent_menu`, `quick_replies` have a `payload` field that you can set.

```
{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload":"<GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD>"
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is about the display of messages and templates in the lite versions of the facebook app. Not the start message.